# python open() vs gzip.open() and file mode

Tags: python, google-bigquery, gzip

Why does file mode differ when using `open()` versus `gzip.open()` from the official [gzip module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/gzip.html)?

Python 2.7 on Linux.

Same thing happens when using `GzipFile` on already open filehandle.

I was thinking it's supposed to be transparent, so why do I see numeric modes and not `rb` / `wb`?

### Test script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Write one file to another, with optional gzip on both sides.

Usage:
    gzipcat.py <input file> <output file>

Examples:
    gzipcat.py /etc/passwd passwd.bak.gz
    gzipcat.py passwd.bak.gz passwd.bak
"""

import sys
import gzip

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    sys.exit(__doc__)

ifn = sys.argv[1]
if ifn.endswith('.gz'):
    ifd = gzip.open(ifn, 'rb')
else:
    ifd = open(ifn, 'rb')

ofn = sys.argv[2]
if ofn.endswith('.gz'):
    ofd = gzip.open(ofn, 'wb')
else:
    ofd = open(ofn, 'wb')

ifm = getattr(ifd, 'mode', None)
ofm = getattr(ofd, 'mode', None)

print('input file mode: {}, output file mode: {}'.format(ifm, ofm))

for ifl in ifd:
    ofd.write(ifl)
```

### Test script output

```
$ python gzipcat.py /etc/passwd passwd.bak
input file mode: rb, output file mode: wb
$ python gzipcat.py /etc/passwd passwd.bak.gz
input file mode: rb, output file mode: 2
$ python gzipcat.py passwd.bak.gz passwd.txt
input file mode: 1, output file mode: wb
$ python gzipcat.py passwd.bak.gz passwd.txt.gz
input file mode: 1, output file mode: 2
```

Secondary question: Is there any good reason behind that, or is it just an  omission / unhandled case in gzip module?

### Background

My actual use case is with Google BigQuery loader which requires the mode to be `rb` before using it as data source. Traceback below. But I prepared minimum test case above, to make this question more readable.

```
# python -c 'import etl; etl.job001()'
Starting job001.
Processing table: reviews.
Extracting reviews, time range [2018-04-07 17:01:38.172129+00:00, 2018-04-07 18:09:50.763283)
Extracted 24 rows to reviews.tmp.gz in 2 s (8 rows/s).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "etl.py", line 920, in wf_dimension_tables
    ts_end=ts_end)
  File "etl.py", line 680, in map_table_delta
    rewrite=True
  File "etl.py", line 624, in bq_load_csv
    job_config=job_config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 797, in load_table_from_file
    _check_mode(file_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 1419, in _check_mode
    "Cannot upload files opened in text mode:  use "
ValueError: Cannot upload files opened in text mode:  use open(filename, mode='rb') or open(filename, mode='r+b')
```

And here is the bigquery API call which *uses* the filehandle:

```
def bq_load_csv(dataset_id, table_id, fileobj):
    client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.source_format = 'text/csv'
    job_config.field_delimiter = ','
    job_config.skip_leading_rows = 0
    job_config.allow_quoted_newlines = True
    job_config.max_bad_records = 0
    job = client.load_table_from_file(
        fileobj,
        table_ref,
        job_config=job_config)
    res = job.result()  # Waits for job to complete
    return res
```

### Update

This problem was fixed in python bigquery client 1.5.0.
Thanks to @a-queue who filed a bug report, and thanks to Google devs who actually fixed it.

Comment: can you share the code you are using to upload to bq?

Comment: @WillianFuks, whole code? unfortunately not. It's just Python api for the BQ which is documented here: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage.html

If you have any concrete questions about using BQ client code I will happily answer, please paste them on SO and give me link here. 

My question here is why the mode property is kinda broken on gzip.open.

Comment: @WillianFuks I have added bigquery api call which raises the exception, does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper way to deal with this is to raise an issue in both Python and Google Cloud Client Library for Python respective issue trackers.

## Workaround

You could substitute `_check_mode` function from `google.cloud.bigquery.client` to accept `1` and `2`, as I did below. I have tried running this code and it works:

```
import gzip
from google.cloud import bigquery

def _check_mode(stream):
    mode = getattr(stream, 'mode', None)

    if mode is not None and mode not in ('rb', 'r+b', 'rb+', 1, 2):
        raise ValueError(
            "Cannot upload files opened in text mode:  use "
            "open(filename, mode='rb') or open(filename, mode='r+b')")


bigquery.client._check_mode = _check_mode

#...

def bq_load_csv(dataset_id, table_id, fileobj):
    #...
```

## Explanation

### google-cloud-python

The trace shows that the last to fail was function  [`_check_mode`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/0267a0c080a2547fa48c8fd39860592306017987/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py#L1435) from `google/cloud/bigquery/client.py`:

```
if mode is not None and mode not in ('rb', 'r+b', 'rb+'):
    raise ValueError(
        "Cannot upload files opened in text mode:  use "
        "open(filename, mode='rb') or open(filename, mode='r+b')")
```

### gzip.py

And in gzip library in the function [`__init__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/gzip.py#L123) of the class [`GzipFile`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7508a54c77e85235e07e344cf9440e5b4695e9cc/Lib/gzip.py#L110) you can see that the variable `mode` was passed to this function but **NOT** assigned to [self.mode](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/gzip.py#L179) but is used to assign an [interger](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/gzip.py#L18):

```
READ, WRITE = 1, 2 #line 18
...
class GzipFile(_compression.BaseStream):
...
def __init__(self, filename=None, mode=None,
    ...
    elif mode.startswith(('w', 'a', 'x')): #line 179
        self.mode = WRITE
```

According to the blame line 18 was changed [21 years ago](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/gzip.py#L18%20https://github.com/python/cpython/blame/7508a54c77e85235e07e344cf9440e5b4695e9cc/Lib/gzip.py#L18) and line 180, `self.mode = Write`, [20 years ago](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/gzip.py#L18%20https://github.com/python/cpython/blame/7508a54c77e85235e07e344cf9440e5b4695e9cc/Lib/gzip.py#L180).

Comment: I would +1 your answer 10 times if I could. Last but not least - for the information about the age of code in question.

Comment: +filiprem There is a [pull](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/pull/5276) request in the official repository with this feature(based on this post). Once the tests are added the request probably will be accepted.

Comment: In any case, if my solution works for you, mark it as a solution. This will immediately indicate to the other visitors that it indeed worked for you. Otherwise they see that this question as unanswered and may completely ignore it.